# response query works in shell but in code gives a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: scrapy

If I do

```
scrapy shell https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery
```

and then

```
response.css('h1#firstHeading::text').extract()
```

i get the correct output of

```
['Electric battery']
```

But if I make this python code ;

```
import scrapy


class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wiki'
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.com']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery']

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.css('h1#firstHeading::text').extract()
```

and I run it I get the error message

```
C:\python\wikipedia>scrapy runspider wiki
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\thega\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 145, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 267, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 347, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 73, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "c:\users\thega\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 779, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 916, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python\wikipedia\wikipedia\spiders\wiki.py", line 11
    print response.css('h1#firstHeading::text').extract()
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am taking the code from a tutorial at https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/build-basic-web-crawler-pull-information-website-2/

I'm confused how the syntax is wrong when it's been tested as working in shell???

Comment: If you are on Python 3 you have to do print statements like this print(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are writing the code for python 2 but running it in python 3 you are missing the brackets,here is the way to do it

```
import scrapy


class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wiki'
    allowed_domains = ['wikipedia.com']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_battery']

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.css('h1#firstHeading::text').extract())
```